# GLSurfaceView hides UI widget

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-camera

I'm placing a GLSurfaceView on top of the output from the camera and drawing onto it. I have a regular layout containing a SurfaceView and TextView:

```
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
<SurfaceView
    android:id="@+id/cameraPreview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/nearest_place_label"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:text="@string/empty"  />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Then I programmatically add the GLSurfaceView:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_bigarrow);
            //...
    cameraPreview = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.cameraPreview);
    mGLView = new MyGLSurfaceView(this);
    addContentView(mGLView, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    previewHolder = cameraPreview.getHolder();
    previewHolder.addCallback(surfaceCallback);
    previewHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);

    nearestPubLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nearest_place_label);
    nearestPubLabel.setText(R.string.bigarrow_searching);
    nearestPubLabel.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);//clutching at straws

}
```

The GLSurfaceView is transparent, apart from a small area of the screen, and I can see the camera preview beneath it. However my TextView isn't visible. When I had this set up with regular views, the TextView was visible.

Answer (score 0):

I switched to loading the GLSurfaceView from XML rather than using `addContentView`, and the TextView is now visible. Doesn't explain what was wrong with the previous approach, but I'm happy for now.